# Erro log when using RemoteTokenServices in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, bearer-token

In my spring boot project, I use `remoteTokenServices` of the available library to generate tokens as well as log in

This is the loadAuthentication function:

```
    @Override
    public OAuth2Authentication loadAuthentication(String accessToken)
            throws AuthenticationException, InvalidTokenException {

        MultiValueMap<String, String> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        if (additionalParameters != null) {
            formData.setAll(additionalParameters);
        }
        formData.add(tokenName, accessToken);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Authorization", getAuthorizationHeader(clientId, clientSecret));
        Map<String, Object> map = postForMap(checkTokenEndpointUrl, formData, headers);

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(map)) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("check_token returned empty");
            }
            throw new InvalidTokenException(accessToken);
        }

        if (map.containsKey("error")) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("check_token returned error: " + map.get("error"));
            }
            throw new InvalidTokenException(accessToken);
        }

        // gh-838
        if (map.containsKey("active") && !"true".equals(String.valueOf(map.get("active")))) {
            logger.debug("check_token returned active attribute: " + map.get("active"));
            throw new InvalidTokenException(accessToken);
        }

        return tokenConverter.extractAuthentication(map);
    }
```

It can be seen that the library has reprocessed exceptions and changed them to: `logger.debug`

Somehow I get erro logs from time to time and can't reproduce this case. Here it is:

```
- Message: [nio-8081-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidTokenException:<MY_TOKEN>
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices.loadAuthentication(RemoteTokenServices.java:135) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:87) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
 at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:134) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.1.jar!/:5.7.1]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar!/:5.7.1]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar!/:5.7.1]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar!/:5.7.1]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar!/:5.7.1]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.
```

I tried instances of the token but couldn't replicate them, my cases are all in the `loadAuthentication` function.

Please let me know the problem I'm having. Thank you everyone!